# Toshiba Satellite L555D BSOD

Tags: bsod

I have this Toshiba Satellite L555D that keeps randomly blue screening even after a clean install of Windows 7. I have also tried runnig a chkdsk and a SFC scan and no errors were found. I have also tried switching to different RAM sticks and the same problems keep showing up.

Here's all of the Memory dump information that I have retrieved for the laptop:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 100113-32791-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 10/1/2013 1:10:24 PM
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`0000003f
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000001
Parameter 4       : fffff800`02cd60d8
Caused By Driver  : rtl8192se.sys
Caused By Address : rtl8192se.sys+3b1c5
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\100113-32791-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 271,416
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 100113-50076-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 10/1/2013 11:12:03 AM
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000007e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff880`011090dc
Parameter 3       : fffff880`02fce5e8
Parameter 4       : fffff880`02fcde40
Caused By Driver  : ataport.SYS
Caused By Address : ataport.SYS+8b71
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : cng.sys+50dc
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\100113-50076-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092513-36675-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/25/2013 4:17:42 PM
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`ffffff84
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000001
Parameter 3       : fffff800`02c9889f
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\092513-36675-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092313-39499-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/23/2013 11:27:54 AM
Bug Check String  : PFN_LIST_CORRUPT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000004e
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000099
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00084855
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00083fb5
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\092313-39499-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 091613-50154-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/16/2013 7:21:27 AM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00005003
Parameter 2       : fffff780`c0000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00004ef1
Parameter 4       : 00004dc7`00009ce2
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\091613-50154-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 091413-54085-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/14/2013 7:55:08 PM
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
Parameter 1       : 00000000`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff880`04805d48
Parameter 3       : fffff880`096f5950
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : dxgmms1.sys
Caused By Address : dxgmms1.sys+5d48
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\091413-54085-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 090513-39062-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/5/2013 5:39:14 AM
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
Parameter 1       : 00000000`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff880`02c4c149
Parameter 3       : fffff880`093a4e40
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : Npfs.SYS
Caused By Address : Npfs.SYS+b149
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\090513-39062-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 090213-42323-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/2/2013 6:34:14 AM
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000001
Parameter 4       : fffff800`02cca410
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\090213-42323-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 081813-42588-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 8/18/2013 3:40:41 PM
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
Parameter 1       : 00000000`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff800`02d9bc32
Parameter 3       : fffff880`096611c0
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\081813-42588-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,600
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 081613-41340-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 8/16/2013 12:11:02 PM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b50
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18229 (win7sp1_gdr.130801-1533)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b50
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\081613-41340-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 278,968
==================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the driver `rtl8192se.sys`. Maybe it's non-compatible or crashed?

Try uninstalling that driver. If you don't see the same BSODs, then the problem was on it. Then do these steps:
1) Reinstall the driver, maybe the driver file was crashed. If you see the same BSODs, then
probably it's not compatible with your hardware/OS.
2) Try updating your driver, if there are newer versions.
3) Contact with support, if nothing changed.

And let me bring some explanation for your error:
`Caused By Driver : rtl8192se.sys` - you must start from here.
It wanted to write to a memory address without required privileges(`0x0000000A`).
And your `Parameter 3` is equal to `0x...01` which means that it tried to `write` to that memory.
And the system gave you BSOD to prevent it.

---

Info: `rtl8192se.sys` is the driver of [Realtek RTL8192SE WLAN adapter](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=230).
So if you want to contact them, you must go [there](http://www.realtek.com.tw/contact/).

Answer (score 0):

The error codes `0x0000000a`, `0x0000001a` and `0x00000050` point to the RAM. Maybe one or more of the RAM modules is faulty. You should download [MemText x86](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) and burn the iso file to either a CD or USB stick and run the test (set the CD or USB stick as the primary boot option through the BIOS).

`0x1000007e` usually points to a corrupted OS as a result of a bad overclock. If you have applied any overclocks, make sure you revert back to the stock settings.

`0x0000003b` is again related to overclocking. This code suggests that the CPU vcore is too low. If you haven't overclocked your processor, you might have to manually increase the CPU vcore through the BIOS.

**Error code source:** [Common Error Codes](http://www.overclock.net/a/common-bsod-error-code-list-for-overclocking)

Answer (score -1):

Install **Nirsoft Bluescreen view** and see which system files are causing BSODs.

Maybe there is no problem with the RAM sticks, maybe it is hard disk, or GPU, or some other hardware issues, or may be it's a faulty driver.